# How to mock up a composited class's method in Scala, expect inhertant to override it

Tags: python, scala, mockito, specs2, python-unittest

I am a few days Scala beginer, swiched from Python. 
I have a class Business which has a field called fasado, fasado 's class has a field - proxy, proxy 's class has field - dao, dao has a method called load_db, how can I mock up this method?

My task is to write a unittest for Business.do_something() 
I need to mock up the method - load_db to return a dummy string.

In Python, I can just patch Dao.load_db()
Since Scala is static type, how can I do it? 
I don't want to use inheritant to override the method, because the relationship between class Business and class Dao could be very complicated.

```
// please don't get confused by the class names,
// it is only a sample, I used meaningful work like DAO for readability
class Business{
    def do_something() = this.fasado.proxy.dao.load_db
    // magic stated
    val fasado: Fasado = new Fasado()
    class Fasado{
        val proxy: Proxy = new Proxy()
        class Proxy{
            val dao: Dao = new Dao()
            class Dao{
                def load_db() = {
                    // connect to db and load data
                    "real db data"
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
object Test{
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val b = new Business()
        println(b.do_something)
    }
}
```

Comment: This example violates some programming principles, [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) explains some of them. [Tell don't ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) and [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) are other principles you are breaking. If I wanted to test these things, I would pass in the dependencies, I would then be able to mock or stub the dependency.

Comment: You say that the dependency between Business and DAO could be complicated. This tells me that you should simplify the relationship.

Comment: In ihe first verison of this question, I was using A, B, C, D ....
I changed the class names to some meaningful word.